# The Entropy of the phrase "Eile Mit Weile"

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, optimization, information-theory, entropy

I want to calculate the Entropy of the phrase "Eile mit Weile". I found the probability of each letter as the following

$$P(e)=\frac{4}{12}$$
$$P(i)=\frac{3}{12}$$
$$P(l)=\frac{2}{12}$$
$$P(m)=\frac{1}{12}$$
$$P(t)=\frac{1}{12}$$
$$P(w)=\frac{1}{12}$$

Then I used the formula for entropy 
$$H(p_1,...,p_k)=-\sum_{i=1}^{k}p_i\log_2(p_i)$$
$$H(p_1,...,p_k)=-(\frac{4}{12}\log_2(\frac{4}{12})+\frac{3}{12}\log_2(\frac{3}{12})+\frac{2}{12}\log_2(\frac{2}{12})+\frac{1}{12}\log_2(\frac{1}{12})+\frac{1}{12}\log_2(\frac{1}{12})+\frac{1}{12}\log_2(\frac{1}{12}))≈2.355388542 \ Bits$$
But the correct answer is $1.63263$ Bits. I've made a mistake somewhere but can't figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that this depends on many assumptions you implicitly took. For instance, you disregard spaces, and the case of each letter. You also assume that each letter is independent, and is generated according to the frequencies of this particular sentence. With the same method, the entropy of "A AaA aa" would be zero, which could be absurd in several scenarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two answers agree, with the following change: it's 1.63263 *nats*, not *bits*. That is, the value 1.63263 is calculated using the natural logarithm.

Comment: How do I convert from bits to nats? And also, would I have to do this conversion every time I calulated the entropy?

Comment: It's a good exercise in logarithms to figure out how to convert from bits to nats and vice versa.

Comment: Whether you have to do it or not, it's up to you. You could do the calculation using the natural logarithm in the first place if you want a result in nats.

Comment: $1$ nat = $\frac{1}{In{2}}$bits and I want to find out what $2.35538854$bits is equal to, I'd just do cross multiplication but I come to the answer $28.2646625$nats - which is wrong

Comment: When I did the calculation it worked out. Try again until it works out for you as well.

Comment: Perfect! I got the answer but my last question is, what's the natural log formula for entropy? Is it the same but replace the $\log_2(p_i)$ with $In$?

Comment: Yes, it's the same with $\log_2$ replaced by $\log_e$.